# CakePHP - exclude css based on specific pages

Tags: cakephp

I have a default css file for all page,but just one page have different css not default.In this situation can I exclude css link by cakephp html helper ?

Comment: What's the problem with including it conditional (based on the current controller/action, a variable passed to the view or similar)? We're talking about the very basics of programming here. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is you can add css links in your view file to the head using CakePHP's blocks feature.  See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks

For example, in the layout, somewhere in the head have:

```
<head>
   ...
   <?php echo $this->fetch('css'); ?>
   ...
</head>
```

This indicates where the css block will displayed.  Then, anywhere in your view files,

```
$this->Html->css('style', null, array('block' => 'css'));
```

And this style sheet will appear in the head.  This way, you can control which css is linked to for each individual action/view.

Another option, is to include in your layout some code like this:

```
<head>
...
 <?php 
    if($defaultCss) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
 ?>
...
</head>
```

Then in your appController, add something like:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('defaultCss', true);
}
```

And in the action that's the exception:

```
$this->set('defaultCss', false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't exclude a css, but you can use a different layout for that page...

Comment: If you don't really know it, then you shouldn't post it as an answer, but use comments instead.